# Continue to run next steps after Element Not Visible Exception in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am currently testing a website. When I click on the check in field a calendar opens and when I click on the next arrow it mininmizes, which is an error. I wrote the script to test this issue, but my problem is I have some script after the error and It won't execute. I am using Selenium Webdriver on chrome and using Extent Reports v3.0.6 to generate the report. I'm using TestNG aswell

I want that particular step to be shown as failed and also the script to continue with the next steps. Will that be possible?

This is my code:

```
@Test
public void test6()
{
    test = extent.createTest("Test Case 6 : Selecting different months from secondary Calendar", "Browsing through and testing the calendar in check in/out field");

    driver.navigate().to("https://www.hoteltreeoflife.com/reservation/");
    test.info("Navigated to first page");

    driver.findElement(By.id("checkIn")).click(); // clicking on checkin field
    test.info("Clicked on Check In field");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-datepicker-div\"]/div/a[2]")).click(); // The test fails on this line since its not visible
    test.info("Clicked on foward arrow to change check in month");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-datepicker-div\"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]")).click();//choosing date AUG 6th
    test.info("Check In Date selected");

    driver.findElement(By.id("checkOut")).click(); //clicking on checkout field

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-datepicker-div\"]/div/a[2]")).click(); //clicking next arrow
    test.info("Clicked on foward arrow to change check out month");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-datepicker-div\"]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[4]")).click();//choosing date AUG 16th
    test.info("Check Out Date selected");

    test.info("Finding Check Availability");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[4]/button")).click();
    test.info("Clicks on Check Availability");
}

@AfterMethod
public void check(ITestResult result) throws IOException
{
    if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE)
    {
        String screenshotPath = GetScreenshot.capture(driver);
        test.fail("Test Case Failed");
        test.info(result.getThrowable());
        test.info("Screenshot Below : " + test.addScreenCaptureFromPath(screenshotPath));

    }
    else if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP)
    {
        test.fail("Test Case Has Been Skipped");
    }
    else 
    {
        test.pass("Test Case Passed");            
    }
}
```

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
```

I dont want to find that element. I want my script to keep running and execute the rest of the code even after the error message

Comment: if you just wanted to bypass the `element not visible` error then put that line in `try` block and rest in `catch` else you waned to handle the exception then you have to use `Explicit wait` until that element get visible . once visible then you can perform further actions.

Comment: @Tuks I tried implementing a `try` block but then the in the report its identified as PASS. I don't want the element to be visible. I want the script to continue with the code below the failed steps

Comment: can you mention the code line which cause `Element not visible` exception ?

Comment: @Tuks `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-datepicker-div\"]/div/a[2]")).click();`

Comment: @Vishal Your tests should be more granular. You are testing moving forward and also other features in same test. Divide it up into separate tests so you will not have to take care of dependency. But if you still want to use your current tests you should use findElements instead which returns a list. And use SoftAssertion of testng to continue on failures - http://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/soft-assert/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

As you mentioned that you `wrote the script to test this issue` so this step itself have a separate validation point which you have to assert and it would be a complete Testcase & should reside with a separate `@Test` annotation. This is inline with  @Grasshopper's idea.

Now also mentioned, you have `some script after the error and It won't execute`. That is the correct behavior. So to get the remaining block get executed you can consider to move the remaining block to a separate `@Test` annotation block.

So, now if `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-datepicker-div\"]/div/a[2]")).click();` throws exception you will get the result as `Fail` and if it passes you will get the result as `Pass`.

> Now as `test7` will depend on `test6` so for `test7` add the clause `dependsOnMethods = "test6"` in the declaration as **`@Test (dependsOnMethods = {"test6"}, alwaysRun = true)`**

Your Final code block will look like:

```
@Test
public void test6()
{
    test = extent.createTest("Test Case 6 : Selecting different months from secondary Calendar", "Browsing through and testing the calendar in check in/out field");

    driver.navigate().to("https://www.hoteltreeoflife.com/reservation/");
    test.info("Navigated to first page");

    driver.findElement(By.id("checkIn")).click(); // clicking on checkin field
    test.info("Clicked on Check In field");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-datepicker-div\"]/div/a[2]")).click(); // If the test pass/fail result is updated.
}

@Test (dependsOnMethods = {"test6"}, alwaysRun = true)
public void test7 ()
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-datepicker-div\"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]")).click();//choosing date AUG 6th
    test.info("Check In Date selected");

    driver.findElement(By.id("checkOut")).click(); //clicking on checkout field

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-datepicker-div\"]/div/a[2]")).click(); //clicking next arrow
    test.info("Clicked on foward arrow to change check out month");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-datepicker-div\"]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[4]")).click();//choosing date AUG 16th
    test.info("Check Out Date selected");

    test.info("Finding Check Availability");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[4]/button")).click();
    test.info("Clicks on Check Availability");
}
```

Let me know if this Answwrs your Question.

Comment: I tried this approach but due to the `@Test (dependsOnMethods = {"test6"})` for some reason `test7` is skipped. So i decided to run it as 2 different steps. Because I dont think after a test fails the rest of the script will keep running in the same method.

Comment: You need to add alwaysRun='true' to your Test annotation on the test7 method. Makes sure that the test run even if the method it depends on fails.

Comment: @Grasshopper Thanks a lot :) Even I am trying to construct something like `@Test (dependsOnMethods = {"test6"}, alwaysRun = true)` trying to test if it would work :)

Comment: @Vishal You must not proceed simply bifurcating into 2 different steps. `test7 ()` will be having a dependency on `test6 ()`, so `@Test (dependsOnMethods = {"test6"})` is mandatory. You can't jump over to `test7 ()` without executing `test6 ()`.Else you have to induce `@Test(priority =6 )`, `@Test(priority =7 )` etc. Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB After I added `@Test(priority = 7)` it seemed to work great. Thanks

Comment: Thats wonderful news. Glad to be able to help you and convince you what should work good for you :) Upvote the Answer if it was useful to you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a method which tell you if element is present or not, and based on that you can fail or pass the test cases. 
There are two way to implement that.

```
 public boolean isElementExist(By identifer, int timeOut){

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOut);

        try{
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(identifer));
            return true;
        }catch (TimeoutException te){
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And the following is without waiting.

```
    public boolean isElementExit(By identifer){
        return  driver.findElements(identifer).size() > 0;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned *I dont want to find that element. I want my script to keep running and execute the rest of the code even after the error message* then simply put the line of code in try catch block

Suppose you expected to get an exception in below line :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-datepicker-div\"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]")).click();//choosing date AUG 6th
test.info("Check In Date selected");
```

then  enclose it in try catch like

```
try
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-datepicker-div\"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]")).click();//choosing date AUG 6th
    test.info("Check In Date selected");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    driver.findElement(By.id("checkOut")).click(); //clicking on checkout field

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-datepicker-div\"]/div/a[2]")).click(); //clicking next arrow
    test.info("Clicked on foward arrow to change check out month");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-datepicker-div\"]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[4]")).click();//choosing date AUG 16th
    test.info("Check Out Date selected");

    test.info("Finding Check Availability");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[4]/button")).click();
    test.info("Clicks on Check Availability");
}
```

**EDIT**

I'm not sure what should be the best answer but if you have the usecase like even if `ElementNotVisibleException` your further code should execute and that test method should count as failed then can try the below method :

```
   if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-datepicker-div\"]/‌​div/a[2]")).isDisplayed())
    {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-datepicker-div\"]/div/a[2]")).click(); // The test fails on this line since its not visible
        test.info("Clicked on foward arrow to change check in month");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-datepicker-div\"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]")).click();//choosing date AUG 6th
        test.info("Check In Date selected");

        driver.findElement(By.id("checkOut")).click(); //clicking on checkout field

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-datepicker-div\"]/div/a[2]")).click(); //clicking next arrow
        test.info("Clicked on foward arrow to change check out month");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-datepicker-div\"]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[4]")).click();//choosing date AUG 16th
        test.info("Check Out Date selected");

        test.info("Finding Check Availability");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[4]/button")).click();
        test.info("Clicks on Check Availability");
    }
    else        
    {

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-datepicker-div\"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]")).click();//choosing date AUG 6th
        test.info("Check In Date selected");

        driver.findElement(By.id("checkOut")).click(); //clicking on checkout field

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-datepicker-div\"]/div/a[2]")).click(); //clicking next arrow
        test.info("Clicked on foward arrow to change check out month");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-datepicker-div\"]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[4]")).click();//choosing date AUG 16th
        test.info("Check Out Date selected");

        test.info("Finding Check Availability");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[4]/button")).click();
        test.info("Clicks on Check Availability");


        org.testng.Assert.fail("Test method Failed due to ElementNotVisibleException");
    }
```

Code Explanation :

If condition will check weather your element is visible or not if it is visible then it will continue your execution if element not visible then it moves in else condition and execute the further code which you want to execute

Once execution done at the end

```
org.testng.Assert.fail("Test method Failed due to ElementNotVisibleException");
```

is used to mark that test method failed as it moves in else condition.

Comment: @Vishal, Please check the updated answer and let me know if any issue

Answer (score 0):

How about doing something like this, would be much cleaner to implement and maintain :

```
public boolean isElementFound(WebElement webs, String stringToFind) {
        try {
            webs.findElement(By.className(stringToFind));
            return true;
        }
        catch (NoSuchContextException e) {
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

You can implement similarly for xpath, ids, etc as per the need. You can call the above function like  
`BaseDriver baseDriver = new BaseDriver();
if (!(baseDriver.isElementFound(webs, "tagClass"))`